# Second Unicode escape sequence in TextBlock not honored

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, unicode-escapes

I'm trying to use the [Unicode character 20dd (COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20dd/index.htm) in a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#x20DD; PASS &#x20DD; FAIL" />
```

The first occurrence is honored and a circle appears before the word "PASS", but the second occurrence is not honored:

[image: Screenshot of how the TextBlock appears]

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your font doesn't have it

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that @SLaks is correct in his comment above. Changing the font to something else did resolve the issue.

However, I still don't understand how the first character would display properly if the font didn't have it. Very strange.